# Show that when angular momentum $L_x$ and $L_y$ commute with operator $G$, then $L_z$ also commutes with $G$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, commutator, lie-algebra

I want to prove that if Angular momentum $L_x$ and $L_y$ commute with an operator $G$, angular momentum $L_z$ also commutes with $G$.

if $[L_x , G] = [L_y, G] = 0$

then $[L_z , G] = 0$

I know that $[L_x, L_y] = ih(L_z)$ and $L^2 = L_x^2 + L_y^2  +L_z^2$

Comment: Hint: Jacobi identity.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, I've tried using it but don't know what aproach I should take. Should I write Lx and Ly using momentum p?

Comment: @WouterA Replace $L_z$ with $[L_x, L_y]$ and expand the final expression.

Comment: @gented Thanks, I found the answer!

Comment: @WouterA If you have found the answer, please post it. After some days, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that,
$$
[L_x,L_y]=2 \;i \;\hslash \;L_z
$$
Consider an operator G, and relations as mentioned
$$
[G,L_x]=0 =[L_x,G] 
$$
$$
[G,L_y]=0=[L_y,G] 
$$
Note: G is an element of the Lie algebra.

Qmechanic gave a really nice hint. If there are three operators A,B and C in a lie algebra, the Jacobi Identity is as follows:
$$
[A,[B,C]]+[B,[C,A]]+[C,[A,B]] = 0
$$
Let, $A = G$ and $B = L_x$ and $ C = L_y$, we thus obtain,
$$
[G,[L_x,L_y]] = 0
$$
We can now use the commutation relation and obtain the result that you wanted, i.e
$$
[G,L_z] = 0
$$